# Using Proxies in objective C while rapidly sending requests

Tags: ios, proxy, afnetworking, asihttprequest

I am looking for a way to send rapid request using proxies to make a viewbot app.  Any suggestions on how to efficiently do this or to make the most use of the proxies and the network ability would be really helpful.  Currently my setup uses ASIHTTPRequest where i setup a request add it into an array and then I have a method that is constantly looping through these request and startAsynchronys.

Comment: what is a "viewbot" ??

Comment: if you have heard of twitch.tv it is essentially making it look like you have a ton a viewers at the same time when you really don't.  You get "featured" based off of the viewers you have and more real viewers will come watch if you already have a baseline viewers if that makes sense.

Comment: oh i see.  but you want to do that ON AN APP. is it images you are fetching?

Comment: no it is essentially just having thousands of request sent to unique url's so that twitch things there are all these viewers.  It also need to support using proxies.

Comment: It turns out u just need a bunch of premium proxies with virgin IP's for it to work.

Comment: sounds like a good tip, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you simply use DLImageLoager, which takes care of all for you?

It is an incredibly well maintained library. We often use it to stack up 100s of calls, never a hiccup.

https://github.com/AndreyLunevich/DLImageLoader-iOS/tree/master/DLImageLoader

Example code for "set and forget" loading an image

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv
         cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    NSInteger thisRow = indexPath.row;
    BooksCell *cell;
    cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:
              @"CellBooksNormal" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    // set text items...
    cell.title = @"blah";

    // set image items using DLImageLoader

    __weak UIBookView *loadMe = cell.anImage;
    [DLImageLoader loadImageFromURL:imUrl
       completed:^(NSError *error, NSData *imgData)
        {
        [loadMe use:[UIImage imageWithData:imgData]];
        }];

    return cell;
    }
```